# Color-code HTML in script templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, color-coding

I've been using script tags for javascript templates like this. (This example uses Handlebars.js but many other templating engines follow the same convention.)

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
        <span>{{ title }}</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Visual Studio does not color code the HTML inside the `<script>` tag. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type does not need to be explicitly `text/x-handlebars-template`, you can use `text/html` instead.  Visual Studio understands this is meant to be interpreted as HTML and will thus color code it appropriately.